# How to use Service management ecosystem(kafka connector) in gravitee 3.x. Is their any guide or tutorial

Tags: apache-kafka, gravitee

Not able to understand how to use kafka connector. do we require our own service to connect to kafka or gravitee will provide.

Answer (score -1):

You can find out more about how to use the Kafka Connector on Gravitee [here](https://docs.gravitee.io/apim/3.x/apim_publisherguide_introducing_kafka.html).

Comment: Provided link is broken, do you have an example of usage of gravitee connector?